# Python ZeroDivisionError When Doing a Calculation With Floats

Tags: python, floating-point

I'm not sure why this keeps happening. I'm trying to calculate the percentage change in a stock price, however, it throws me an error.

```
p = ((current - past) / past) * 100
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

This is the function:

```
def getPercent(past: float, current: float):
    p = ((current - past) / past) * 100
    return round(p, 2)
```

And I am printing the results using str(getPercent()).
Any idea why this causes this error?

Comment: for which input you getting the error?

Comment: give your input value

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can get zero division error here is if `past` is `0`. You can use try-clause.

```
def getPercent(past: float, current: float):
    try:
        p = ((current - past) / past) * 100
        p = round(p, 2)
    except:
        p = 'undefined'
    return p
```

Or, use a small `eps` while dividing for numeric stability.

```
def getPercent(past: float, current: float):
    eps = 1e-9
    p = ((current - past + eps) / (past + eps)) * 100 # considering past is never - eps
    return round(p, 2)
```